# MSVCR120.DLL Required

Tags: c, dll, msvcrt

I was asked to download the specified DLL after running one of my apps on a secondary computer. The only problem is whether or not it should have been required. I obviously code in Visual Studio, but it is in pure "C" and a Win32 project, so I'm just wondering if this is normal.

Comment: are you trying to run a debug build as opposed to a release build on the machine without VS?

Comment: Nope. It is a release build. If it was a debug build, then it would have required MSVCR120D.dll.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706421/visual-studio-2013-msvcr120-to-msvcr100

Comment: Redistributable package worked for me. Does anyone know if this is normal for a pure "C" program?

Comment: always - unless you change the linkage see answer below, or in the linked question in my comment. I always build release with static linkage as its a pain if you then want to run on another machine that may or may not have the runtime. if pure c the difference in file size will be negligable.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to load CRTs, change run time library to static library. (MT)

or you need these dlls in installed visual studio\VC\redist

//after your comments//

MSxx##D.dll D means Debug.
if you link any library built with debug run-time, the exe needs debug runtime library