# Build c++ exe without dependencies

Tags: c++

I want to build some program using C++ to work without `c++ redistributable` ,
I am using Toolset Visual Studio 2013 (v120) But show error `msvcr120.dll missing` when execute on Machine does not have microsoft visual c++ redistributable package .

**Any idea to build without dependencies**

Comment: You can add libs as static libs instead

Comment: look into the args MD vs MT https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757418/should-i-compile-with-md-or-mt note that if you have libraries, they too will all have to be built with the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706421/visual-studio-2013-msvcr120-to-msvcr100

Comment: If this is a simple 1 executable project with no dlls it will be easy to switch to a static CRT.

Comment: @Abel same i think should use vs build tools v100

Comment: v120 v100 doesnt matter much.  just give the right args to statically link.